# How to ensure markers in Google Map Flutter don't overlap each other?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

I have a Google Map with about 100+ markers with custom icons using Canvas and Painter. If the map is at a small zoom level, the markers will overlap.

I want every time I zoom or move the map, if any two markers overlap by about 10% of the area, the marker below will be hidden. I want to display as many markers as possible as long as they don't overlap.
Please let me know the solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe this package can help you https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_cluster_manager